# How do you link to a direct message conversation on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to generate a link that opens the direct message conversation for 2 users in the browser.

I thought the link would be like this:

```
https://twitter.com/messages/[HEADER_TWITTER_TO_ID]-[HEADER_TWITTER_FROM_ID]
```

But for some reasons that doesn't always work and instead I have to use this:

```
https://twitter.com/messages/[HEADER_TWITTER_FROM_ID]-[HEADER_TWITTER_TO_ID]
```

Does anyone know how to decide which user ID comes first in the link?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked with my conversations and it seems the first value is always the one with the smallest Twitter ID of both, except when you have a chat with yourself (yes, I do that...).